# Deploy Vue.js App as Azure App Service from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, vue-cli

I have a Vue.js app. This app was created using the [Vue-Cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/). At this time, this is a basic "hello world" app. I have this app running on my local machine. I run it by using `npm run serve` from the Terminal window in Visual Studio Code. I'm now trying to deploy this app from Visual Studio Code to an Azure App Service.

I have an Azure App Service created. I also installed the [Azure App Service Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice). From the "Terminal" window in Visual Studio Code, I entered "npm run build". This created a directory named "dist". I then right-click on that directory and choose "Deploy to Web App...". I then choose my subscription and app service name and choose "Deploy". I see a prompt that says "Deployment to "." I then click the "Browse Website" button. This launches a browser window. In the browser, I see a splash screen that says "Hey Node developers!" However, I was expecting to see my Node.js app. What am I missing?

In an attempt to deploy this app, I ran `npm run build` from the "Terminal" window. This created a "dist" directory.

Comment: Can you please navigate to https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/ and go to debug console>cmd. Do you your site files show up here?

Comment: @BryanTrach-MSFT When I visit `sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net`, I do not have a debug console > cmd option. Instead, I have "Environment", "SSH" and "Bash". I suspect you are referring to an App Service on Windows, however, this is apparently and App Service on Linux.  When I use the Bash shell, I see a directory named "site". Inside of "site", I see a directory named "wwwroot". Inside of "wwwroot" I see my files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please refer to the [Local Git Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git) as per the Microsoft Docs.**

Failing that, you could try to deploy manually via FTP. You can do that by going to your Azure Portal:

`App Service => Deployment Center => FTP => Dashboard`

You'll then find some FTPS credentials on that page and all you have to do is deploy your `dist` folder up to `/site/wwwroot`, see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp).

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation wasn't so clear and many tutorials no longer woking since Azure has updated some of its features. I tried directly deploy the `dist` folder under `/site/wwwroot` by my **API requests** were not functioning properly.

After some digging, I eventually got my **vue.js** app successfully deployed onto Azure App Service, with functioning **routing**, and **API requests**.

The key here is to deploy SPA on Azure App Service as **Static website**. As Azure defines static website as

> *"A static site is typically a single-page application (or SPA) written with Angular, React or Vue. However you design the app, you host and serve these files directly from storage rather than using a web server. Hosting in storage is simpler and less expensive than maintaining a web server."*

Following this link below and using **Azure Storage** and **VSCode** should get the job done.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial-vscode-static-website-node-01?tabs=bash

Comment: Azure Storage is a different product.   And while it will serve up your static SPA (as it has a web server), the problem is you cannot point a custom domain to it.

Comment: Here from the official doc it states you can map a custom domain to Azure blog storage.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: I did ran into more issues deploying Vue onto Azure using Blog Storage. So I later changed to use Azure Devops and set up CI/CD pipeline/release and connected to the Azure app service.